# MyFaces never throw exception for undefined custom tags

Tags: jsf-2, custom-controls, facelets, taglib, myfaces

I'm trying to write some custom Facelets 2.0 tags, after several hours work, I found that my UIInput subclass is not even instantiated. Then, I changed the actual namespace to something like:

```
<html xmlns:my="http://bad-namespace">
...
<my:foo />
</html>
```

You see, now `my` points to an non-existing namespace `http://bad-namespace` which should raise something error, however, no exception raised,  `<my:foo />` is just silently skipped!

So, I can't make my tag work, and I can't see any error, too. I have just no idea what to do. I'm new to develop custom Facelets 2.0 tags, though. I have googled tutorials on Facelets 2.0 custom tags, but didn't get much information, mostly are focused on the old JSF 1.2.

Comment: I don't do MyFaces, so I can't post a reliable answer from top of head, but Mojarra only warns that when project stage is set to development. Is yours also set as such? MyFaces might behave similarly. Set in `web.xml` the `<context-param>` of `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` to `Development`. You should see (at least, in Mojarra) some orange warning line at the page bottom which reads like *"Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http:// bad-namespace declared with prefix my but no taglibrary exists for that namespace."*

Comment: @BalusC: Thank you. Luckily, the question was resolved by declare component-type in faces-config.xml instead of @FacesComponent annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked and MyFaces does not show anything. This seems to be a good feature to add on MyFaces. In theory it is valid to put namespaces and pass it to the generated document, so it is not a bug, but in practice a warning on dev time does not harm. I created this issue for you [MYFACES-3215](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3215), to deal with it, so stay tuned with MyFaces [Users and Dev Lists](http://myfaces.apache.org/mail-lists.html) because this will be added in future releases.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are a kind person.